# How can I track how many IIS requests have been served via perfmon?

Tags: iis, perfmon

What is the best way to track the total number of IIS requests have been served using Perfmon. I am wanting to track sover a time period the total number of requests served but Google and searching is failing me.

Am I best using, W3SVC_W3WP(_Total)\Requests / Sec counter, take the value every second and add it up to get a requests served over a minute value?

Answer (score 0):

In the end we using "W3SVC_W3WP", "Total HTTP Requests Served", "_Total" over a 2 minute window. Taking the result at the start and the end, we found a great delta of the total number of requests.

All the other counters found were per second and didnt reflect the result we wanted. Which was how requests a farm were serving.